# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error

Tags: mysql, iis, odbc, oledb

I am getting the following error.

Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80040e21'

ODBC driver does not support the requested properties.

C:\Local_Path/tblPlaylist.asp, line 4

I have setup the website in IIS

The line 4 in the code is

```
rs.Open "SELECT numPlaylistID FROM `tbl_playlist-page` WHERE numPageID=" & Cint(numPageID), dbConn, 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason for that is the cursor type that is being specified.  The `1` in the `Open` call indicates a keyset [cursor type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681771%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (adOpenKeySet).  That can result in 0x80040e21 error depending on the underlying driver.  You might try changing it to another value as a test (e.g., change to 0 for a forward only cursor).